# fsockopen, can't get a foot in! Connection timeout

Tags: php, sockets, connection-timeout

Excuse my terrible pun.

Basically, the deal is, the host is being a bitch. A simple `fsockopen` script, no matter what port, server, or anything, will connect. Trying to get server help from the webhost (due to unfortunate circumstances I have no way of changing hosts) proved ineffective... bunch of morons. A simple `phpinfo()` shows, however, that `allow_url_fopen` is **on** and `Registered Stream Socket Transports` allows me `tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls`.

So, what am I missing? Does it sound like the host is discreetly blocking socket connections? I mean, even port 80 doesn't work:

`Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to www.google.com:80 (Connection timed out)`

Comment: Can you connect by IP address? Could be a DNS problem...

Comment: @DaveRandom - a DNS problem would not return a `Connection timed out` error; you'd get  "`php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known ...`"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provided you are calling `fsockopen` correctly (you don't show code), that error is implying that yes, they are restricting you from making outbound connections.

```
$fp = fsockopen("www.google.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
}
```

If you have shell access, try using telnet and you should see the same result:

```
telnet www.google.com 80
```

Comment: Just what I thought, but I needed confirmation that it was the case. That is actually the code I am using (copied from PHP documentation). They provide shell access... or try to at least; it doesn't actually work. Ah the wonderful world of web hosting...

Comment: Sounds like you need a new web host :)